# Cisco ASA EEM Run command weekly

Tags: cisco-eem

I'm currently looking into using the EEM for not yet defined tasks.
It looks like I can only create events that run daily at a specific time or every x seconds (I guess I can build a weekly event with this). However, what I'm missing is the possibility of running events e.g. every Monday or similar.

I'm used to just building something with cron on Linux so this seems a little light-weight to me. Am I not seeing something here or is this a function that the ASA just does not offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're accustomed to cron, my recommendation would be to use it with key-based ssh to run your periodic functions.  Perhaps on a small dedicated solid-state server, perhaps a fleet of cloud-based redundant ones, depending on your other parameters.

Cron-type functions tend to be very poor and very varied across routers, switches, bridges etc, and so you get good harmonisation if you can move it server side.  For example a config master host which pulls configs periodically is a great start, and nice to have it independent of manufacturer and software versions.

Comment: This is not ideal but I guess I'll go with this. The Cisco EEM seems to be poorly equipped.